# OWA SSO with ADFS fails on Firefox

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, adfs, ws-federation, outlook-web-app

I have successfully completed SSO between OWA and ADFS.

Now the problem is the SSO only works on Chrome and not on Firefox.

On Firefox, OWA sends multiple requests to ADFS and after 6 requests, ADFS gives an error.

ADFS version: 4.0

Windows Server: 2016 Standard

Below is the error from ADFS:

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '6' seconds. Contact your administrator for details.

Comment: Is ADFS expecting Kerberos authn? If so, you're gonna need to configure FF to do it... It doesn't do it by default.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your response. Not really. I know that if we are using Kerberos we have to configure browsers to support that. But I did not configure anything on Chrome and this is a fresh installation.

Comment: Chrome in Windows uses the Windows networking stack, so it does Kerberos with no special configuration. Firefox uses its own stack, so it has to be configured. The fact that Chrome is working as expected days even more: Configure Firefox for Kerberos.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not automatically perform Kerberos authentication against any sites. You must manually add sites to a trusted sites list.

To enable Kerberos authentication in Firefox:

1. Open Firefox and enter `about:config` in the address bar, Dismissing warnings that appear.
2. In the **Filter** field, enter `negotiate`.
3. Double-click the `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` preference.
4. This preference lists the trusted sites for Kerberos authentication.
5. In the dialog box, enter the fully qualified domain name of the ADFS server, for example `adfs.example.com`.
6. Click the OK button.

The domain that you just entered in the `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` should now appear in Value column. This setting takes effect immediately; you do not have to restart Firefox.

Comment: I did not know OWA uses Kerberos with ADFS. After adding the configuration you mentioned it worked on normal mode but when I try SSO with Incognito mode it fails with same error. Any idea? Thanks for answer by the way.

Comment: OWA doesn't use Kerberos... ADFS does. Usually, ADFS is configured so that it falls back to some other authentication method if Kerberos doesn't work, but in a pure MS environment, that isn't always necessary. It will be if you want OWA to be accessible from mobile devices, though. As far as Firefox goes, I don't think it supports Kerberos in private browsing. Private browsing is supposed to remove identifying information, and Kerberos isn't private.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. I really appreciate this.

Comment: If I can ask another favour? Can you help me with Claims rules which needs to be sent to OWA when I am receiving Email from Claims Provider?

Comment: Sorry... I'm not an ADFS guy. You're best asking that at the Microsoft community, probably.

Comment: No issue. Thanks for your help!